# How can we to run GPU with C# in Encog Framework?

Tags: c#, gpu, encog

How can we to run GPU with C# in Encog Framework ?

I see that we have a c++ GPU command in Encog Framework.
(http://www.heatonresearch.com/encog/encog_gpu.html)

Do we have a C# function in Encog Framework, to send the encog process on the GPU ?

Answer (score 0):

GPUs has many cores so your kernel function is the only one that runs on GPU. To run encog on GPU you need to make a wrapper around encog and port it to GPU. I will suggest not to do that unless your neural network widely uses images.

> CUDA is actually in C and C++ so you can easily integrate it on GPU. But in the case where your choice is C# you can use command line tool in the same way as you use command prompt.

I hope this helps.